# How to install Solidity on Windows?

Tags: solidity, installation, windows

I've been following the tutorial at https://www.ethereum.org/greeter , but when it gets to the point of installing Solidity, it is apparently no longer maintained on chocolatey so that step doesn't work.

How should I go about installing Solidity?

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck at the step of getting solc to compile your solidity contracts:

- Go here: https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/v1.2.1
  (Or to the newest release available)
- Click on cpp-ethereum-1.2.1 Windows Installer
- Install it
- Verify you have solc available
- Continue greeter hello world tutorial :-)
- And of course: Open a new issue: https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org/issues/new and make a reference to where the greeter is located: https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org/blob/develop/views/content/greeter.md#install-solc-on-windows also reference: https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org/pull/151

Comment: it seems the links are out-of-date already.

Comment: an newer post: https://www.codeooze.com/blockchain/solc-hello-world/