# contract.address is undefined when deploying a contract with cpp-ethereum and ethconsole

Tags: contract-deployment, cpp-ethereum

I want to create new contract using cpp-ethereum (built from source) and 
ethconsole. I followed this guide: https://www.ethereum.org/greeter.

I modified the contract to contain only one class without functions to minimize the gas cost:

```
contract greeter{   
}
```

I'm doing this on test network and I have 5 ether on my account.

Here's the js code that I got after using online Solidity compiler:

```
 web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){
    var account = accounts[3];
    console.log("Using account: " + account);
    var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract([]);
    var greeter = greeterContract.new(
    {
        from: account, 
        data: '6060604052600a8060106000396000f360606040526008565b00', 
        gas: 3000000
    }, function(e, contract){
        console.log(e);
        console.log(contract.address);
        if (typeof contract.address != 'undefined') {
            console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
        }
    })
  })
```

This is the output that I get:

```
null
undefined
```

For some reason, contract is not deployed, function returns no error and contract.address is undefined.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide has a different function:

```
if(!e) {

      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }

    }
```

Indeed, this function will be called **twice**.

- The first time, it will be with the transaction hash. Do `console.log(contract);` to convince yourself.
- The second time, it will be with the contract itself. Provided there is a node mining.

Comment: For some reason, the cpp-ethereum binaries that I've built from source did not include solidity compiler. I've downloaded 1.2.1 build, mentioned in this question: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/how-to-install-solidity-on-windows and I was able to execute code from the guide that you mentioned. It worked! Thanks.